# Mongodb error: Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1

Tags: mongodb, centos7

Installed mongodb few weeks ago and it was working fine, but today I found an error in the server(centos7)

When I tried to connect it was the answer

```
mongosh -u user-p password --authenticationDatabase admin
Current Mongosh Log ID: *****
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionT  imeoutMS=2000&authSource=admin&appName=mongosh+1.9.1
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Version of mongo

```
db version v6.0.6
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.6",
    "gitVersion": "***",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "rhel70",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

This is the error when I try to restart in centos web panel:

```
Environment variable MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK == 1, overriding "processManagement.fork" to false
```

Log file

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.136+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.138+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.140+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.140+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.407+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.407+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.407+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T23:16:54.407+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23330,   "ctx":"main","msg":"ERROR: Cannot write pid file to {path_string}: {errAndStr_second}","attr":{"path_string":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","errAndStr_second":"No such file or directory"}}
```

I couldnt find /var/run/mongodb,  but it was working fine, any idea what could happen or what to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you run into this one: [Directory in /var/run gets deleted after hard reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/74796/directory-in-var-run-gets-deleted-after-hard-reboot)

Check the service file, e.g. with `systemctl cat mongod`

In order to make mongod running, I put these lines in the file:

```
[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/lib/mongo
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0700 /var/lib/mongo
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
```

or the newer version would be

```
[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre+=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre+=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre+=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre+=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/lib/mongo
ExecStartPre+=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo
ExecStartPre+=/usr/bin/chmod 0700 /var/lib/mongo
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
Type=forking
```

Note, usually you don't edit service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` directly. It might be reverted when you run any updates of MongoDB. Instead, create a copy to `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` and put your customized settings there. See [What's the difference between /usr/lib/systemd/system and /etc/systemd/system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206315/whats-the-difference-between-usr-lib-systemd-system-and-etc-systemd-system/458252#458252)

Another note, some systems use `/run` instead of `/var/run`. See [Difference between /run and /var/run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175345/difference-between-run-and-var-run). Have a look at your file system and/or your config file, e.g. `etc/mongod.conf`:

```
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```