# Mongodb fails to start

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, system, systemd

After following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04) to install `MongoDB` in ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine, everything was working fine until I modified on `/etc/mongod.conf` just to comment out `#security:` and enable the authorization, like this :

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I restarted the `mongod.service` using `sudo systemctl restart mongod` and when I checked its status using `sudo systemctl status mongod` it threw this error:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-07-11 09:47:40 UTC; 27s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 161380 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 161380 (code=exited, status=14)

Jul 11 09:47:39 WafrMainNginxStagingServer systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 11 09:47:39 WafrMainNginxStagingServer mongod[161380]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-11T09:47:39.869Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":7484500, "ctx":"main>
Jul 11 09:47:40 WafrMainNginxStagingServer systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Jul 11 09:47:40 WafrMainNginxStagingServer systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So I tried to uninstall mongoDb and all its files permanently, and reinstall it from the beginning but without any luck, I keep getting the same error even without modifying on any file.

after some debugging I tried to modify on `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` and commented those two lines :

```
[Service]
#User=mongodb  <---
#Group=mongodb <---
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
Environment="MONGODB_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_NOFORK=1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
RuntimeDirectory=mongodb
```

I commented the `User` and `Group` lines, then I reloaded the systemd `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, and it worked :

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-07-11 10:02:39 UTC; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 161613 (mongod)
     Memory: 160.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─161613 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

Jul 11 10:02:39 WafrMainNginxStagingServer systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 11 10:02:39 WafrMainNginxStagingServer mongod[161613]: {"t":{"$date":"2023-07-11T10:02:39.056Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":7484500, "ctx":"main>
```

I wonder why, is there a way to get it working without commenting the `User` and `Group` lines? since I might get some another errors in the future because of this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, the problem was just from user group permissions, I just had to give `var/lib/mongodb` the required permissions

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

and did the same thing with mongodb socket

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

then restarted the mongod.service `sudo systemctl restart mongod`, and now it is working like a charm.

Comment: To avoid this error in future, I modified my service file like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369342/mongodb-error-environment-variable-mongodb-config-override-nofork-1/76370516#76370516  You have to modify/delete the `.sock` file only after an unclean shutdown, by default you don't need to touch it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That's actually a great solution, thanks for the information, it would be better than changing the permissions manually whenever running into this problem.