Starting mongodb via systemctl and a non-default directory
I'm debugging a mongodb (7.0) instance which should start via systemctl on AlmaLinux 9 and use a non-default data directory (/data/mongo) - after the typical problems and googling, the file permissions on /data/mongo are set to mongod:mongod. There still are errors that there are insufficient file-permissions - on explicitly that path.
The weird thing is, that if mongod is started via "sudo -u mongod mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf" it works. The systemctl config is set to use that user and weirdly it also works when the default directory is specified.
To summarise:

it works via systemctl on the default directory
it works on the non-default dir if started via "sudo -u mongod mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf"
it doesn't work via systemctl and the non-default dir

Also checked the uid/gid on the directory and they match what is in passwd ...
Any ideas?
Cheers and thanks
Edit: solved after two days ... the SELinux policies which are in the instructions assume the default directory: https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-selinux/tree/master

First you should show us the /etc/mongod.conf and preferable also the service file. And the error messages. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187641/mongodb-systemctl-start-failure-due-to-dbpath-keyfile-path-permission-error/69187822#69187822 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369342/mongodb-error-environment-variable-mongodb-config-override-nofork-1/76370516#76370516

What do you mean by "default directory"? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090 How can you use different directories when you start it with systemctl? For this you would need to have different configuration files. Did you follow Configure SELinux?
